# CanCan - Testing Abilities for a Model's field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Hello I have the following

Models:

```
User (id)
Room (user_id, title)
RoomMember (user_id, room_id, admin)
```

Given: 
    @user1
    @user2
    @user3
    @room

@user1 created the room and is a room admin. @user1 should be make @user2 a RoomUser.admin. @user3 who is not an admin should not be able to make @user2 a RoomUser.admin. That's what I want to write a spec for but can't figure out how to test this with CanCan. Here is what I have so far:

room_member is the @user2 RoomMember record for the Room

```
  ability.should be_able_to(:update, room_member.admin)
```

Any advice on how I can write a spec for this w CanCan?

Thanks

**Updated with my ability**

In the specs:

```
#Ability (user, room, room_password)
room_member = @room_for_user_1.room_members.create(:user_id => @user_2.id)
ability = Ability.new(@user_1, @room_for_user_1, nil)
```

Comment: Are you asking about testing the ability, or is your problem really that you're not sure how to define this ability?

Comment: I know how to define the ability I have that going. What I don't know how to do is test the ability in terms of one field in the object. I only want other RoomMember.admins to be able to make another RoomMember.admin

Comment: Please show your Ability definition for this task.

Comment: updated. Right now I made Ability.rb, for testing purposes, can [:manage], RoomMember .. just so I can figure out how to write the spec to test the field

Comment: Here it the spec error I get: xpected to be able to :update true
     # ./spec/models/ability_spec.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: What I don't get is in the CanCan docs, to test abilities it's always at the model level, Project.new for example. It never takes into account whether that user has person on said project or not

Comment: What I meant to ask for was your definition in Ability.rb - without that it's hard to give specific examples. I could show you some of my rules and tests, but that's less helpful than addressing your code.

Comment: @Jeremy I mention that 2 comments up. Maybe you can share an example of writing a ability and spec that is for a object's field (@ room_member.admin) and how to test that in rpsec? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on CanCan, but I don't think you can define the ability in the way you are trying. As far as I've seen in the docs and examples, actions are only defined on the record, not on record attributes.

When you want to define an ability that does not confer complete control over the record, you need to define a custom action.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize (user = nil)
    user ||= User.new
    can :set_admin, [ Room ] { |room| user.room_members.any?{ |rm| rm.room == room && rm.admin? } }
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you only want the room owner to control room admins, this would be `can :set_admin, [ Room ] { |room| room.user == user }`.

Then it is straightforward to test: `ability.should be_able_to(:set_admin, room)` or, depending on the variables you have in your test: `ability.should be_able_to(:set_admin, room_member.room)`